# slidetoggle not working wrong class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a slidetoggle but it's not working. Generrally if I hovered on the year the months will display via slidetoggle but its not working...Probably the class on the script is wrong. Sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h0mzezn7/2/)

HTML:

```
    <div class="smart-archives">

    <ul>
        <a class="year-link" href="http://net/2015">2015</a>: 

        <li><a class="month-link" href="http://.net/2015/01" title="1 post">January</a></li>
        <li><a class="month-link" href="http://.net/2015/02" title="1 post">February</a></li>
        <li><a class="month-link" href="http://.net/2015/03" title="16 posts">March</a></li>
        <li><a class="month-link" href="http://.net/2015/04" title="13 posts">April</a></li>
<li><a class="month-link" href="http://.net/2015/05" title="9 posts">May</a></li>
<li><a class="month-link" href="http://.net/2015/06" title="4 posts">June</a></li>
<li class="empty-month">July</li>
<li class="empty-month">August</li>
<li class="empty-month">September</li>
<li class="empty-month">October</li>
<li class="empty-month">November</li>
<li class="empty-month">December</li>
</ul>

    <ul>
<a class="year-link" href="http://.net/2014">2014</a>:
<li class="empty-month">January</li>
<li><a class="month-link" href="http://.net/2014/02" title="14 posts">February</a></li>
<li><a class="month-link" href="http://.net/2014/03" title="25 posts">March</a></li>
<li><a class="month-link" href="http://.net/2014/04" title="11 posts">April</a></li>
<li><a class="month-link" href="http://.net/2014/05" title="11 posts">May</a></li>
<li><a class="month-link" href="http://.net/2014/06" title="5 posts">June</a></li>
<li><a class="month-link" href="http://.net/2014/07" title="4 posts">July</a></li>
<li><a class="month-link" href="http://.net/2014/08" title="6 posts">August</a></li>
<li><a class="month-link" href="http://.net/2014/09" title="6 posts">September</a></li>
<li><a class="month-link" href="http://.net/2014/10" title="3 posts">October</a></li>
<li><a class="month-link" href="http://.net/2014/11" title="4 posts">November</a></li>
<li><a class="month-link" href="http://.net/2014/12" title="1 post">December</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
ul li { display:none; }
.empty-month { display: none; }
```

SCRIPT:

```
$("ul > li").hover(function () {
    $(this).children("ul li").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should slide toggle `sibling` `li`s on hover of `anchor` as below:

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/h0mzezn7/3/)**</kbd>

```
$("ul > a").hover(function () {
    $(this).siblings("li").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

and you might face below problems here if you keep that option on `hover`

> - It might not work on properly on mobile
> - It will not allow you to click on the months once you <kbd>`hoverout`</kbd> of the link

So What I suggest is do the same functionality on `click` like

<kbd>**[DEMO FOR CLICK](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/h0mzezn7/5/)**</kbd>

```
$("ul > a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings("li").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Comment: its working but when i hover on the month it deactivates the hover how can still display this? via css or is it doable on js?

Comment: ok great. i think its better to use click than hover. but it is possible on hover? and control the li display setting using css?

Comment: Its possible but you need might need to use either `show` and `hide`  or `slideUp` or `slideDown` instead of `slideToggle`, check the scenario inside `hover` and then `hide` or `show` again

Comment: You might need to look at this **[question and answer](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/3uLxb/48/)**  otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

`li` is the old valid child of `ul` so

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="year-link" href="http://thegypsetters.net/2015">2015</a>:</li>
    <li><a class="month-link" href="http://thegypsetters.net/2015/01" title="1 post">January</a>
```

then

```
$("ul > li:has(.year-link)").hover(function () {
    $(this).siblings().slideToggle("fast");
});
```

and

```
ul li {
    display:none;
}
ul li:first-child {
    display: list-item;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cfbcrjx7/)